# Plot data of multiple axis using GUI?

Tags: matlab-guide

I have two variables namely ft1<195x1 double> and ft2<195x1 double> and two axis namely axis1 and axis2(created using GUIDE).
I want to plot these variables on these axis respectively.
How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help, if you have the handles-struture of your GUI-> when using within a button-callback for example, you should already have it:

```
%1. make the first axes the current-axes:
axes(handles.axes1)
%2. plot:
plot(ft1,additional arguments...)
%3. make the second axes the current-axes:
axes(handles.axes2)
%4. plot again:
plot(ft2,additional arguments...)
```